# Why does no one drop into my public Payday 2 game?

Tags: payday-2, xbox-one

## Update 8/21/15

Due to the number of views on this question, I thought I should update about the situation, which is that Xbox One players still cannot join each other's games if they are not *specifically invited* to the lobby.

This is a well-known, ongoing, and much lamented issue with XB1 Payday 2. Since the original post, the behavior of the broken matchmaking has changed with subsequent patches, but the issue is not fixed. Check out the [Overkill Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/overkill_tm) for more information.

=====================

### Original Post

I'm playing on Xbox One, with the Payday 2: Crimewave Edition. My NAT ports are open, i have Fios boosted speed, everything technical is fine according to the XB1 network and multiplayer tests. Other games work perfectly fine.

In payday though, i play a lot with one other person. One of us always goes to crime net, selects an "untaken" job (no gamertag above it), and then invites the other person to the game. Its the easiest way to join each other in payday.

The game we create is always set to public, with drop-in allowed, no reputation limit, and playing with AI. We didnt mind playing a game or two alone at first, but after a dozen games in a row, we noticed no one was dropping into our game.

**We have never had another person jump into a game we have created, since the midnight game launch last Tuesday.** It doesnt matter who creates the game, if it's just one person or the two of us, any map, any difficulty. No one drops into the game.

Am i doing something wrong? We can separately join a hosted game from crime net perfectly fine, and invite the other person if there's room in the lobby (and if no one else jumps in first), but thats a really annoying procedure.

I want to make a public game, invite a friend, and then have strangers fill the empty slots. Anyone know how?

*Note: we had this game on 360 and did NOT have this issue*

Comment: How many people are generally on Crime.Net at the time?

Comment: i generally see at least a dozen open games, i just turned it on now (early morning EST) and there are 16 open games. That sounds about average to me.

Comment: just for reference too, @MattR i am playing on east coast US, any time from 5pm to midnight weekdays. i play any time of day on weekends, but this weekend is the first weekend for payday 2 to be out on xb1. I'll  make sure to update this post if i see the behavior change at any particular time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that overkill haven't sorted out the connection problems with the game. Its not that people aren't trying to join you its the fact that every time someone try's it just comes up with connection errors, failed to join. Overkill are supposed to be worked on a patch but that was over a week ago.

Comment: Overkill do seem to take ages to fix issues at times.  Have you got a link to where they said they were working on a patch, or where it says that is the problem?

Comment: sounds logical but why can i join other people's games then? i don't get an error

Comment: i am now getting failures when i try to join games, i guess i just had some good luck on launch day. hopefully it will get patched soon.

Comment: overkill stated on twitter they are working on a patch but its a week old. Btw don't hold out much hope guys, i had payday 2 on pc and whenever they had to patch something it would take them weeks to do it.